# Nested Async Await Does not Wait

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, async-await

I think I missunderstanding the behaviour of `async` `await` in c#.

I have two methods that return a `Task` defined like

```
public async Task Name()
{
await AsyncOperation() 
}
```

Imagine `AsyncOperation()` like an `PostAsync` of `HttpClient`.

Now I call them inside some other methods

```
public asyn Task Method()
{
await Name1(() => { "bla bla"});
await Name2();
Console.WriteLine("Continue");
}
```

This works as expected to me. Waits until `Name1()` and `Name2()` finish and then continues.

Now I need to nest `Name1()` and `Name2()`. In fact `Name1()` is a Please Wait Window that recieve as lambda parameters a slow operation, while `Name2()` is a slow download of a file. I want the Plese Wait window appears while the file is downloaded.

So I try something like this:

```
public asyn Task Method()
{
    await Name1( async ()=>
    {
        await Name2();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Continue");
}
```

In this case the execution doesnt wait untile `Name2()` finished. Why this happen and `await` doesnt wait?

**Update**

This is the logic behind the method of please wait. It shows a Please Wait message using [Mahapps Dialogs](http://mahapps.com/controls/dialogs.html), executes the code that recieves by the lambda, and then close the please wait message.

```
public static async Task Name1(Action longOperation)
{
    _progressController = await _metroWindow.ShowProgressAsync("Please wait...");            
    await Task.Run(() => longOperation());
    await _progressController.CloseAsync();
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without seing the the code for your Name1 method taking the lambda. What does it do internally with that lambda?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24777253/1997232).

Answer (score 7):

The `Name1` method takes a delegate and returns a `Task<T>` where `T` is the type returned by the delegate. In your case, the delegate returns `Task`, so we get `Task<Task>` as the result. Using `await` waits only for the completion of the outer task (which immediately returns the inner task) and the inner task is then ignored.

You can fix this by dropping the async and await in the lambda function.

Also, take a look at [Asynchronous Gotchas in C#](http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/04/async-csharp-fsharp).

Comment: Couldn't he revise his `Task.Run` to `await Task.Run(async() => await longOperation());` to return control back to the calling member until the long operation completes? This way his await carries all the way, including the nested await?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger, if `longOperation` is already *async* (returns a `Task`), you very rarely need to wrap it with `Task.Run`. It'd only make sense if there's a chunk of blocking or CPU-intensive code at the beginning of `longOperation`, or if you want to execute it without sync. context. If you do wrap it, `await Task.Run(() => longOperation())` would be enough (no need for an `async` lambda).