# Waiting for async/await inside a task

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

I have this construct in my `main()`, which creates

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    async () =>
    {
        Foo.Fim();
        await Foo.DoBar();
    });

//DoBar not completed
t.Wait();
//Foo.Fim() done, Foo.DoBar should be but isn't
```

However, when I `.Wait` for t, it won't wait for the call to `DoBar()` to complete.
How do I get it to actually wait?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: [Stephen Taub wrote a great article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx) about how to start tasks. There's actually an example in that article which looks *exactly* like your example (i.e. `Task.StartNew(async() => ...)`) and which explains what's going on

Answer (score 114, accepted):

It's discouraged to use `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`, you should be using `Task.Run` instead:

```
var t = Task.Run(
    async () =>
    {
        Foo.Fim();
        await Foo.DoBar();
    });
```

The `Task.Factory.StartNew` api was built before the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx) and `async-await`. It will return `Task<Task>` because you are starting a task with a lambda expression which happens to be async and so returns a task. `Unwrap` will extract the inner task, but `Task.Run` will implicitly do that for you.

---

For a deeper comparison, there's always a relevant Stephen Toub article: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)

Comment: Interesting, that is a sneaky difference for `Task.Run`. This additionally answers my confusion about why Task.Run is different with the async/awaits. Thanks.

Comment: @NathanCooper that's what happens in a library with incremental additions and no breaking changes.

Comment: Yeah, my understanding was that it was the same with different defaults. Being equivalent to `"Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, 
    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);"` as the article says. This clearly needs further reading when your using async/await rather than simple actions.

Comment: I was losing my mind today trying to find out why Factory.Start was returning Task<Task... even though all my code looked kosher.

Thanks!

Comment: Was about to ask about how to pass the LongRunning parameter using the new factory, and then found this excellent blog post you wrote: http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/  

Your answer combined with that post really helped me out!

Answer (score 8):

It seems like I get desired functionality by `Unwrap()`ing the task.
I'm not quite sure I get the reasoning behind this, but I suppose it works.

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            async () =>
                {
                        Foo.Fim();
                        await Foo.DoBar();
                }).Unwrap();
```

edit: I've looked for ddescription of `Unwrap()`:
`Creates a proxy Task that represents the asynchronous operation of a Task<Task<T>>`
I thought this was traditionally what the task did, but if I need to call unwrap I suppose that's fine.

Comment: Yep, the other answer is pretty comprehensive. `Task.Run()` seems the way to go.

Comment: Are you sure you need `Foo.Dim()` inside the task, in the first place? I.e., maybe you can simply do this: `Foo.Fimm(); Foo.DoBar().Wait();` - without creating a new `Task` via `Run` or `StartNew`.

Comment: @Noseratio Fair point. I've not given the context to show why it is needed (it is), but its always good to check whether we've over-engineered things.

Comment: `Unwrap()` just ends up throwing a `Start may not be called on a promise-style task.` exception :/

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue recently and figured out that all you need to do is have `DoBar()` return some value and use .Result instead of wait.

```
var g = Task.Run(() => func(arg));

var val = g.Result;
```

This will wait for `func` to return its output and assign it to val.

Comment: -1 because the OP wasn't looking to return a value, the OP's question was about async/await where this is purely synchronous, and this seems to be returning a throwaway value for the sake of calling Result instead of Wait(). If you wanted to do the above in an async manner, you'd use "var val = await g;" to await the result of the task. If you don't care about the result, then you can simply .Wait() on the task--no need to return a throwaway value from your function and wait using Result.

Comment: his question was "How do I get it to actually wait ? ". where has he said anything about return value ?