# await Task.Delay() vs. Task.Delay().Wait()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, wait, async-await

In C# I have the following two simple examples:

```
[Test]
public void TestWait()
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        Task.Delay(5000).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    });
    t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("All done");
}

[Test]
public void TestAwait()
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    });
    t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("All done");
}
```

The first example creates a task that prints "Start", waits 5 seconds prints "Done" and then ends the task. I wait for the task to finish and then print "All done". When I run the test it does as expected.

The second test should have the same behavior, except that the waiting inside the Task should be non-blocking due to the use of async and await. But this test just prints "Start" and then immediately "All done" and "Done" is never printed.

I do not know why I get this behavior :S Any help would be appreciated very much :)

Comment: Task.Delay is non-blocking. I see no reason why you would use the 2nd construct.

Comment: @RoyDictus they both have their own issues. You should never call`Task.Wait()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Waiting for async/await inside a task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777253/waiting-for-async-await-inside-a-task)

Comment: In the Main() method you can't use "await." You have to use Wait() or the old Thread.Sleep().

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The second test has two nested tasks and you are waiting for the outermost one, to fix this you must use `t.Result.Wait()`. `t.Result` gets the inner task.

The second method is roughly equivalent of this:

```
public void TestAwait()
{
  var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start");
                return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Task.Delay(5000).Wait(); Console.WriteLine("Done");
                });
            });
            t.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("All done");
}
```

By calling `t.Wait()` you are waiting for outermost task which returns immediately.

---

The ultimately 'correct' way to handle this scenario is to forgo using `Wait` at all and just use `await`. `Wait` can cause [deadlock issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13140523/await-vs-task-wait-deadlock) once you attached a UI to your async code.

```
    [Test]
    public async Task TestCorrect() //note the return type of Task. This is required to get the async test 'waitable' by the framework
    {
        await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }).Unwrap(); //Note the call to Unwrap. This automatically attempts to find the most Inner `Task` in the return type.
        Console.WriteLine("All done");
    }
```

Even better just use `Task.Run` to kick off your asynchronous operation:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task TestCorrect()
    {
        await Task.Run(async () => //Task.Run automatically unwraps nested Task types!
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start");
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        });
        Console.WriteLine("All done");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks that worked :) By the way is it always okay to use Task.Run instead of Task.Factory.StartNew or are there cases where I would need Task.Factory.StartNew that Task.Run cannot handle? :)

Comment: Task.Run(someAction); is a convenience wrapper and equivalent to Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction,
    CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);

Comment: @DanielLeiszen: `Task.Factory.StartNew(someAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default);` does not unwrap nested Task types, so it's not strictly equivalent to `Task.Run(someAction);`.