# Why does Thread.Sleep work but Task.Delay does not?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

In my code I assume that `outerFlag` will be hit after `innerFlag` but it actually runs like fire and forget (`innerFlag` is hit after `outerFlag`). When I use `Thread.Sleep` instead of `Task.Delay` flags are hit in correct order.

Here is the code:

```
[Test]
public async Task Test() {

    bool innerFlag = false;
    bool outerFlag = false;

    await Lock(async () => {
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        innerFlag = true;
    });

    outerFlag = true;

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
}

private Task Lock(Action action) {
    return Task.Run(action);
}
```

I also noticed that when I call `Task.Delay` and set `innerFlag` without a `Lock` method but by direct lambda, it works as expected.

Can somebody explain such behaviour?

Comment: That's because `Lock` takes a delegate, and in your case this delegate returns a task. But you don't await that task, so it's a fire and forget task. Basically you just blast by `await Lock(...)` and the 2 second delay inside the delegate will wait and then set innerFlag to true, but you've already ignore that task and just continued to execute.

Comment: If you change `Lock` to `private async Task Lock(Func<Task> func) { await func(); }`, it might work better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [await Task.Delay() vs. Task.Delay().Wait()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798845/await-task-delay-vs-task-delay-wait)

Comment: Well of course it runs like fire and forget -- you pass a `Task`-returning method to something eating an `Action`, meaning the task so produced is ignored. In essence, you're getting exactly what you asked for. (Note that if you want actual locking/exclusion, which this decidedly is not, you want to use something like `SemaphoreSlim` or [`AsyncLock`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock) -- do not attempt to reinvent the wheel here with your own boolean flags, as that will almost certainly run into subtle bugs.)

Comment: @defaultlocale no, your question doesn't answer this one

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen thanks, your solution worked! You can post the answer

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has already been answered here, so I'd rather leave it for someone to find the duplicate and close it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Hi, I am actually writing a lock logic using `SemaphoreSlim` :)
Just removed this from my example, but now after returning Func<Task> it works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Lock` method doesn't understand async delegates, so the async delegate you are trying to pass as argument is treated as `async void`. Async voids are problematic in all sorts of ways and [should be avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void), unless they are used for their intended purpose, as event handlers.

To ensure that your method understand async delegates you must create an overload that accepts a `Func<Task>` as argument:

```
private Task Lock(Func<Task> func)
{
    return Task.Run(func);
}
```

Notice that the `func` argument can be passed directly to [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run), because this method understands async delegates too. Not all built-in methods understand async delegates, with notable examples the [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.startnew) and [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach). You must be cautious every time you add the `async` modifier in a delegate. You must be sure that the called method understands async delegates, or else you may end up with async voids and the havoc they create.