# Using async/await in a task

Tags: c#, task

I want create a task, which itself calls a async method.

```
  var task = new Task(async () =>                    {
                        var res = await asyncMethod();   
                        Console.WriteLine("Async");
                    });
  task.start();


Task.WaitAll(task);
Console.WriteLine("Finished");
```

When running this code "Finished" is returned before "Async".
I guess its because the async lambda is executed independendly from the created task.
Is it possible in a task to wait for another async method?

Comment: Yes, `task` just starts `async() => ...` and that's *all* (*fire and forget* mode), so `task` completes immediately

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777391/1997232).

Comment: Never use `new Task` and then call `Start` on it – these are mainly intended for internal use. You should use `Task.Run`.

Comment: @ckuri But when I use Task.Run the task starts immdedialtly? I want to start several taks at once and before that I create them with my code

Comment: @J.Doe: Then use `Func<Task>`. [There are **zero** use cases for the `Task` constructor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/05/a-tour-of-task-part-1-constructors.html).